# What drawing technology would be appropriate?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm building an iOS application that will be drawing diagrams for the user to see and manipulate (move, add, remove elements) and I'm having trouble choosing how to implement the actual rendering.

I find the default cocoa-touch controls to be too limited for this purpose yet graphics frameworks such as Quartz/OpenGL ES/Cocos2D seem a bit overkill.

Can anyone suggest an approach to this situation or perhaps a library better suited to my needs?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the default controls limit you?

Comment: @Ben Alpert Well the diagrams are drawn on a canvas and all components (boxes and associations) can be moved freely.  I'm having trouble figuring out how this type of functionality can be achieved gracefully through the default set of controls but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have each drawn object (box, association) be a custom UIView subclass added as a separate subview of your main view. Each subview can catch events from finger touches.

Apple's [Touches](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code shows how to receive events on subviews and move them in response to dragging motions.

Comment: Thank you.  As you can see, I'm no iOS deve pro, but this was exactly the kind of advice I was looking for.

Comment: I'm no pro either (yet!) but I've actually been looking into this sort of stuff in the last couple of weeks, so that's why I knew of that example.